# Как вывести изображение с OpenGL2 поверх изображения с камеры

Tags: java, android, opengl, ar

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста (может у кого пример есть простой) как вывести изображение с OpenGL2 поверх изображения с камеры. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ivanovolegdevstudio.iknow_1.ar.ui.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout   **//СЮДА ВЫВОЖУ OpenGL**
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_height="331dp"
        android:layout_width="198dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="118dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="124dp">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.ivanovolegdevstudio.iknow_1.ar.gv.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"   **//Сюда вывожу видеопоток с камеры**
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <com.ivanovolegdevstudio.iknow_1.ar.gv.GraphicOverlay
            android:id="@+id/graphicOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </com.ivanovolegdevstudio.iknow_1.ar.gv.CameraSourcePreview>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

В activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!supportES2()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "OpenGL ES 2.0 is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
        glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new OpenGLRenderer(this));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //setContentView(glSurfaceView);
        glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.la);
        relativeLayout.addView(glSurfaceView);

    }


package ru.startandroid.l176texturecube;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.os.SystemClock;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_FLOAT;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glActiveTexture;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glBindTexture;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClear;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glClearColor;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glDrawArrays;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glDrawElements;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glEnable;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glGetAttribLocation;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glGetUniformLocation;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glUniform1i;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glUseProgram;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer;
import static android.opengl.GLES20.glViewport;

public class OpenGLRenderer implements Renderer {

    private final static int POSITION_COUNT = 3;

    private Context context;

    private FloatBuffer vertexData;
    private ByteBuffer indexArray;

    private int aPositionLocation;
    private int uTextureUnitLocation;
    private int uMatrixLocation;

    private int programId;

    private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mMatrix = new float[16];

    private int texture;

    public OpenGLRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig arg1) {
        glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        createAndUseProgram();
        getLocations();
        prepareData();
        bindData();
        createViewMatrix();
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        createProjectionMatrix(width, height);
        bindMatrix();
    }

    private void prepareData() {

        float[] vertices = {
                                // вершины куба
                -1,  1,  1,     // верхняя левая ближняя
                1,  1,  1,     // верхняя правая ближняя
                -1, -1,  1,     // нижняя левая ближняя
                1, -1,  1,     // нижняя правая ближняя
                -1,  1, -1,     // верхняя левая дальняя
                1,  1, -1,     // верхняя правая дальняя
                -1, -1, -1,     // нижняя левая дальняя
                1, -1, -1      // нижняя правая дальняя
        };

        vertexData = ByteBuffer
                .allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asFloatBuffer();
        vertexData.put(vertices);

        indexArray =  ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(36)
                .put(new byte[] {
                        // грани куба
                        // ближняя
                        1, 3, 0,
                        0, 3, 2,

                        // дальняя
                        4, 6, 5,
                        5, 6, 7,

                        // левая
                        0, 2, 4,
                        4, 2, 6,

                        // правая
                        5, 7, 1,
                        1, 7, 3,

                        // верхняя
                        5, 1, 4,
                        4, 1, 0,

                        // нижняя
                        6, 2, 7,
                        7, 2, 3
                });
        indexArray.position(0);

        texture = TextureUtils.loadTextureCube(context, new int[]{R.drawable.box0, R.drawable.box1,
                                                                R.drawable.box2, R.drawable.box3,
                                                                R.drawable.box4, R.drawable.box5});
    }

    private void createAndUseProgram() {
        int vertexShaderId = ShaderUtils.createShader(context, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, R.raw.vertex_shader);
        int fragmentShaderId = ShaderUtils.createShader(context, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, R.raw.fragment_shader);
        programId = ShaderUtils.createProgram(vertexShaderId, fragmentShaderId);
        glUseProgram(programId);
    }

    private void getLocations() {
        aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "a_Position");
        uTextureUnitLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "u_TextureUnit");
        uMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "u_Matrix");
    }

    private void bindData() {
        // координаты вершин
        vertexData.position(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, POSITION_COUNT, GL_FLOAT,
                false, 0, vertexData);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);

        // помещаем текстуру в target CUBE_MAP юнита 0
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);

        // юнит текстуры
        glUniform1i(uTextureUnitLocation, 0);

    }

    private void createProjectionMatrix(int width, int height) {
        float ratio = 1;
        float left = -1;
        float right = 1;
        float bottom = -1;
        float top = 1;
        float near = 2;
        float far = 12;
        if (width > height) {
            ratio = (float) width / height;
            left *= ratio;
            right *= ratio;
        } else {
            ratio = (float) height / width;
            bottom *= ratio;
            top *= ratio;
        }

        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
    }

    private void createViewMatrix() {
        // точка положения камеры
        float eyeX = 0;
        float eyeY = 2;
        float eyeZ = 4;

        // точка направления камеры
        float centerX = 0;
        float centerY = 0;
        float centerZ = 0;

        // up-вектор
        float upX = 0;
        float upY = 1;
        float upZ = 0;

        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ);
    }


    private void bindMatrix() {

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMatrix, 0);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, mMatrix, 0);
    }

    long TIME = 10000L;

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);

        // вращение
        setModelMatrix();

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexArray);
    }

    private void setModelMatrix() {
        float angle = (float)(SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % TIME) / TIME * 360;
        Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 1, 0);
        Matrix.scaleM(mModelMatrix,0,100/angle,100/angle,100/angle);
        bindMatrix();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для прозрачности необходимо в activity

```
glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        glSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        glSurfaceView.setRenderer(new OpenGLRenderer(this));
        glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        glSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

В OpenGLRenderer

```
@Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig arg1) {
        glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        createAndUseProgram();
        getLocations();
        prepareData();
        bindData();
        createViewMatrix();
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    }

@Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);

        // вращение
        //setModelMatrix();

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexArray);
    }
```